# how to go through each field

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway to go through each field in the target list (both source and target list is identical) and update? so i have this code but i dont want to program fields manually.

```
# Load SharePoint CSOM assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

# Set SharePoint site URL and credentials
$siteUrl = "https://your-sharepoint-site-url"
$username = "your-username"
$password = "your-password"

# Connect to SharePoint site
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

# Get List-A and List-B
$listA = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List-A")
$listB = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List-B")

# Load list items from both lists
$ctx.Load($listA)
$ctx.Load($listB)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Get all items from List-B
$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
$listBItems = $listB.GetItems($query)
$ctx.Load($listBItems)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Compare List-B items with List-A using DocNum and Rev fields
foreach ($itemB in $listBItems) {
    $docNumB = $itemB["DocNum"]
    $revB = $itemB["Rev"]

    # Find matching item in List-A based on DocNum and Rev
    $queryA = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
    $queryA.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='DocNum' /><Value Type='Text'>$docNumB</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Rev' /><Value Type='Text'>$revB</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>"
    $itemA = $listA.GetItems($queryA).FirstOrDefault()
    $ctx.Load($itemA)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    if ($itemA) {
        # Update List-B field values if necessary
        if ($itemA["Field1"] -ne $itemB["Field1"] -or $itemA["Field2"] -ne $itemB["Field2"]) {
            $itemB["Field1"] = $itemA["Field1"]
            $itemB["Field2"] = $itemA["Field2"]
            $itemB.Update()
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Updated List-B item $($itemB.Id)"
        }
    }
}

# Disconnect from SharePoint site
$ctx.Dispose()
```

Here is a separate script to compare fields

```
# Load SharePoint CSOM assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

# SharePoint site URL
$siteUrl = "https://your-sharepoint-site-url"

# Credentials (you can use different authentication methods)
$credentials = Get-Credential

# Initialize client context
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials.UserName, $credentials.Password)

# Specify the list names
$list1Name = "ListA"
$list2Name = "ListB"

# Get the lists
$list1 = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($list1Name)
$list2 = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($list2Name)
$context.Load($list1)
$context.Load($list2)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

# Retrieve the list fields dynamically
$fields1 = $list1.Fields
$fields2 = $list2.Fields
$context.Load($fields1)
$context.Load($fields2)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

# Compare fields
$commonFields = $fields1 | Where-Object { $fields2.InternalName -contains $_.InternalName }

# Print the common fields
Write-Host "Common fields:"
foreach ($field in $commonFields) {
    Write-Host "Internal Name: $($field.InternalName)"
}

# Clean up
$context.Dispose()
```